# MongoDB subdocument projection

Tags: mongodb

Need some help with a Mongo query based on the value of a subdocument attribute but also suppressing that subdocument attribute from appearing in the results.

Here are my user objects:

```
{
  "username" : "abc",
  "emails" : [
    {
      "address" : "abc1@email.com",
      "default" : true
    },
    {
      "address" : "abc2@email.com",
      "default" : false
    }
  ]
},
{
  "username" : "xyz",
  "emails" : [
    {
      "address" : "xyz1@email.com",
      "default" : false
    },
    {
      "address" : "xyz2@email.com",
      "default" : true
    }
  ]
}
```

My goal is to get the following output (with "emails.default":true but without the "emails.default" attribute appearing in the results):

```
{
  "username" : "abc",
  "emails" : [
    {
      "address" : "abc1@email.com",
    }
  ]
},
{
  "username" : "xyz",
  "emails" : [
    {
      "address" : "xyz2@email.com",
    }
  ]
}
```

Using the $ positional operator:

```
collection.find({"emails.default":true}, {"username":1,"emails.$":1})
```

I get the correct email subdocuments to appear, but I still get the "emails.default" attribute back:

```
{
  "username" : "abc",
  "emails" : [
    {
      "address" : "abc1@email.com",
      "default" : true
    }
  ]
},
{
  "username" : "xyz",
  "emails" : [
    {
      "address" : "xyz2@email.com",
      "default" : true
    }
  ]
}
```

and for some reason, when I use this statement:

```
collection.find({"emails.default":true}, {"username":1,"emails.address":1})
```

I get the following result (as though the query part of the statement were ignored)

```
{
  "username" : "abc",
  "emails" : [
    {
      "address" : "abc1@email.com",
    },
    {
      "address" : "abc2@email.com",
    }
  ]
},
{
  "username" : "xyz",
  "emails" : [
    {
      "address" : "xyz1@email.com",
    },
    {
      "address" : "xyz2@email.com",
    }
  ]
}
```

Help much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

With the positional operator (as at MongoDB 2.6) you can't selectively exclude fields of the array element you are matching on.

However, you can use the Aggregation Framework in MongoDB 2.2+ to achieve your desired outcome:

```
db.user.aggregate(

    // Match on relevant documents to optimize query
    { $match: {
        username: "abc"
    }},

    // Convert the "emails" address into a stream of documents
    { $unwind: "$emails" },

    // Only include the emails with default:true
    { $match: {
        "emails.default" : true
    }},

    // Project the desired fields
    { $project: {
        _id : 0,
        username: 1,
        "emails.address": 1
    }}
)
```

Sample result:

```
{
    "username" : "abc",
    "emails" : {
        "address" : "abc1@email.com"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a supported feature. You are asking for projection of selected fields inside of a document of an array. See this [ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-828)

But I think your document structure will be storing lots of redundant data. There is going to be only one default email address. Make this a part of the parent document. Updates/Projections will be much more simpler. Your array `emails` now would actually store *only* emails.